# Добавление приложения в правый нижний угол Windows

Tags: python, windows, kivy, виджет

Вопрос будет немного глупым, но я не нашел ничего по этой теме в гугле(

Я хочу написать небольшое приложение по типу ежедневника и добавить его в правый нижний угол(как например звук или часы).

Как я смогу добавить туда программу и надо будет как-то заморочиться с дизайном?
И смогу ли я создать такую программу на python kivy?

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать QT, который будет работать в трее. По клику на иконку в трее повесь функцию запуска скрипта на Kivy. Ну, и с помощью win32API потом сворачиваешь и разворачиваешь окно Kivy приложения при необходимости.

```
import time
import sys
import types
import os

from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication, QAction


class ProgramTray(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, icon):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.icon = QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))
        self.flag_exit = True

    def run(self):
        """Код работающий в отдельном потоке"""

        while self.flag_exit:
            time.sleep(2)

        QApplication.quit()

    def open(self):
        """Запуск Kivy скрипта."""

        os.system("python3 main.py")

    def stop(self):
        self.flag_exit = False

    def setMenu(self, menu=None):
        """Устанавливает пункты меню по клику на иконку в трее"""

        if not menu:
            menu = []

        collection = OrderedDict(menu)
        items = collection.keys()
        functions = collection.values()

        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            function = functions[i]
            if isinstance(function, types.MethodType) or isinstance(
                function, types.FunctionType
            ):
                self.menu.addAction(QAction(item, self, triggered=function))

        self._exit = QAction("Exit", self, triggered=self.stop)
        self._open = QAction("Open", self, triggered=self.open)
        self.menu.addAction(self._exit)
        self.menu.addAction(self._open)
        self.icon.setContextMenu(self.menu)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
program = ProgramTray("icon.png")
program.setMenu()
program.icon.show()
program.start()
app.exec_()
```